# Can NOT query a subscriber by its subscriber key

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql

I haven't queried data from the `_Subscribers` data view before and faced with that issue. Please correct me if I did something in a wrong way.

At first, I created a temporary data extension with these fields:
SubscriberKey - Text - 254 - nullable
EmailAddress - EmailAddress - 254- nullable
Status - Text - 50 - nullable

A SQL query was created also and targeted to the temporary data extension above.
The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
EmailAddress,
Status
FROM _Subscribers
WHERE SubscriberKey = '003O000001TzbzvIAB'
```

And run once. There is nothing returned into the data extension. I tried to remove the line `WHERE SubscriberKey = '003O000001TzbzvIAB'`, it returned 825 results into the data extension.

I also double checked in All subscribers list/Search/Subscriber Key is equal to 003O000001TzbzvIAB and and still found the subscriber.

(Note: I did the query from a Dev Business Unit)

Thanks.

Comment: Are you able to try again with ENT._Subscribers in the query?

Comment: You are right.  `ENT._Subscribers` is the proper way to query. I have checked the document, it seems Data views only stored records in current 6 months

Comment: The 6 month limitation is only on the views around transient or activity data (Clicks, Bounces, Opens, etc) views like Subscribers contain all relevant subscribers in the account.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend querying ENT._Subscribers and also go into the All Subscribers section of Email Studio Subscribers & search the subscriber key you care about (003O000001TzbzvIAB). If that subkey exists in All Subs it will also give the corresponding EmailAddress. From there I would recommend running your query to filter on that email address value EG:

```
SELECT
SubscriberKey,
EmailAddress,
Status
FROM ENT._Subscribers
WHERE EmailAddress= '*result from all subs search'
```

If you still cant find anything there is another way to check contacts information:
Go to
Contact Builder > All Contacts > Mobile List tab > Create Mobile List > MobileConnect > All Contacts

In the filter:
-System Data > EmailAddresses Email Address = '*result from all subs search'
OR
-System Data > Contact > Contact ID = "003O000001TzbzvIAB"

Hope this helps you,

Weenus23